# How can i use dyndns and send emails from it?

Tags: email, server, smtp

How can i use dyndns with ubutntu and send emails from it ?

I want create a free domain with dyndns.com (mydomain.dyndns-at-home.com)

How can I link the domain with ubuntu ?

How can I send emails from this domain ? (info@mydomain.dyndns-at-home.com)

Answer (score 2):

karthick87 linked to a good post on getting dyndns up for others connecting to you.  the problem with sending emails, however, is "what mail relay is going to trust a dyndns domain?"  I would talk to my internet provider and see if they'll allow that sub-domain to send emails on their mail relay.  until you find an amicable mail relay the rest of the configuration is a moot point.

Comment: Right on... it's trivial to send email from *any* PC with an SMTP server running - the problem is getting the email delivered anywhere without it being rejected.

Answer (score 1):

Check this link,

http://bobbyallen.wordpress.com/2008/05/18/dyndns-client-setup-on-ubuntu/

There you get all the details..

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.